# Debugging Matlab C S-function with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, matlab

I have a problem debugging a Matlab S-function written in C. The source code is analysis.c, after mexing this file by

mex -g -v analysis.c

I obtain "analysis.mexw32" and "analysis.mexw32.pdb".

In Visual Studio 2010, I open "analysis.c", attach it to the process "Matlab" and set a breakpoint. So far, this breakpoint is not accepted:

"Breakpoint not hit. No symbols loaded."

When I run the file in Matlab, everything is executed without hitting the breakpoints.
Can anybody give me some advise with this?

I have done this before, and it worked straightforward.

Comment: this may seem silly, but can you build the classic `yprime.c` example in the same directory as `analysis.c` and try to successfully hit a breakpoint?

Comment: I can build it in the same folder, but the breakpoints aren't hit. The pdb file is generated.

Comment: same here even after 3 years. What a pain in the ***. The symbols are not loaded in Visual studio 2010 and already lost 3 hours trying to try different things.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've more-or-less followed the instructions in the [MATLAB help](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f32489.html). Can you double check that you've followed them exactly, please? For example, have you opened exactly the same C-file?

My first suggestion would be to make sure that you've configured your mex compiler to be the same installation of Visual Studio using `mex -setup`.

Comment: Yes, I followed the Matlab help. The C-file is the same. Running mex -setup shows me that there are only 2 compilers available:         [1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011a\sys\lcc 
[2] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in C:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 <-- The one I choose.

Comment: I also get this:               --> cl  /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /FoC:\DOKUME~1\BENDER~1.WIN\LOKALE~1\TEMP\MEX_CS~1\analysis.obj -IC:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011A\extern\include -IC:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011A\simulink\include /Z7 -DMX_COMPAT_32 analysis.c

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by making a change in the "Attach to process" settings. I had to choose "system own code" in the dialogue, after that the symbols were loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using Native Code ,while attaching process to Matlab , it works , breakpoints are hit . hurray ,

Answer (score 0):

My setup with yprime.c as described very badly here:
http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html

```
Tools-Options-Debugging-General - "Enable just my code" is unchecked.
Tools-Options-Debugging-Native - Load DLL, Enable RPC Debugging.
Tools-Options-Debugging-Symbols - 
1. Uncheck Microsoft Symbol servers.
2. Add the *location* of your pdb file by clicking on new folder.
3. Cache symbols in this directoy in my case is empty.
Attach process -> *Automatic : Native code* -> Matlab
Debug -Windows- Modules should show your module (pdb file ) now.
```

I noticed in one of the situation that the symbols were still not being loaded inspite of the above written processs. But one of a module called OnDemand... was present in the Debug-Windows-Modules.
So put a breakpoint even if Visual Studio does not show your module or the breakpoint complains that no symbols are loaded. Go ahead and run the program from Matlab yprime(1,1:4), then the symbol would be loaded on demand and the breakpoint would be activated. Atleast in my case I could.
Phew !